# Installing new module in Drupal 8.3.2 link is not exist in xampp

Tags: theming, 8

I installed drupal 8.3.2 in xampp (localhost). But i can't add new modules like themes,image slider etc.. What I want to do?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the **Update Manage**r module weather it is enabled or not. If it is disabled then enable it.

OR

[Installing Modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/extending-drupal-8/installing-modules)

[How to Install Modules in Drupal 8](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/drupal8/module-installation)

Comment: Update manager module i installed. But again i can't add new module

Comment: But my problem is "install new module link" is not exist :s

Comment: Have you follow the manual process.

Comment: Bro, How to do manual process

Comment: Follow the steps of @karolw. Try some other browser and clear the cache as well (" admin/config/development/performance").

Comment: Ya bro, Thanks for answer, when i clear the cache its, new link 'install new module' link came.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61145/discussion-between-rijo-and-smalution).

Answer (score 1):

Just download zip unzip it and paste folder to xampp\htdocs\modules. It should be working then.

Comment: Bro i unzip and added FlexSlider module, it came in extended section. What should i do next?

Comment: http://localhost/admin/modules just go here and you should be able to enable it. When i got this error it worked for me.

Comment: enable button is not working

Comment: what os are you using

Comment: windows 7 os i'm using. One more thing i'am new in drupal. I installed in localhost, but i want to add slider. I know how to add custom slider using full html but, is this not right way right?